# Add camera layer on irregular shape images IOS

Tags: ios, swift, overlay, masking

I need to add the camera layer on any irregular shaped image i.e. lets say i have a image which is having irregular shape and inside image there is a circular or any other irregular shape in which i want to embed the live camera.

Any idea how i can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Don't know why the question is downvoted? Can the person who did down vote explain this?

Comment: I downvoted this question because I can't vote to close it. Yeah I think you are asking for implementation of feature and didn't even show how you tried to solve it by yourself.

Comment: I have just asked for the idea/ways to implement if you can again read my question. There is nowhere written for the implementation. So it doesn't make sense to downvote the question.

Comment: Did you try to add AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as circular or any other irregular shape?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko circular is possible but not any irregular shape.

Comment: @iAviator What exactly issues do you have with irregular shapes?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko Im able to set the camera layer mask property with the image mask. But the issue now i face is the camera layer is shown in the image where there are colors in the image but i need to show the camera layer in the transparent area of the image. Any idea?

Comment: Im able to put the videoPreviewlayer in image transparent area. Now the problem i face is to save the image with the preview layer merged in image.? Any ideas on this guys?

Answer (score 4):

You can use UIBezierPath to draw irregular share for a mask CAShapeLayer

```
let size = 200.0
```

Create a CAShapeLayer and draw shape in which you wanna embed a cameraPreviewLayer.

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let maskPath = UIBezierPath()
maskPath.move(to: .zero)
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: -size))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size/2, y: -size))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size*2, y: size))
maskPath.close()
maskLayer.anchorPoint = .zero
```

Set the mask positon

```
maskLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 400)
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

self.yourVideoPreviewLayer.mask = maskLayer
self.yourVideoPreviewLayer.masksToBounds = true
```

Or you can make an image with a shape in which you wanna embed a cameraPreviewLayer. Or if your image's inner shape have an alpha value = 0 you can reverse alpha of your original image and use it as a mask.

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.anchorPoint = .zero
maskLayer.frame = videoPreviewLayer.bounds
maskLayer.contents = YourReversedImage.cgImage

self.videoPreviewLayer.mask = maskLayer
self.videoPreviewLayer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I have not used any path for the layer. And as answered above in comments i was able to achieve the layer mask through imageview lask property. Now the issue is when i mask the image of camera and the mask image the code returns the original image. I referred at https://www.innofied.com/implementing-image-masking-in-ios/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Now the issue is when i mask the image of camera and the mask image the code returns the original image." Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Add additional UIView upon of your UIImageView with same frames(width, height and position). it shouldn't be a subview of UIImageView!

Set background of this UIView to `clearColor` and create whatever layer you want.

Now you can use this layer as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer instead of using UIImageView layers